# What's that? It seems, they were meteoroids but i am not sure, please help!

Tags: astronomy, interstellar-matter, meteoroids

[image][image][image][image][image]

I guess that thing must be meteoroid!
Strange thing about them was they appear and disappear then appear again! 
I think that was meteoroid but why were some of them disappearing and reappearing?
P.S. this process took around 1 minute, and there were nothing any symptoms of meteoroid!(as shown in some YouTube videos)

Comment: Couldn't they just be man-made lights, like the other lights in the photo?

Comment: Possible, but they were in some height and area below that is covered with forest(I guess)!

Comment: It is possible to place lights on tall towers, chimneys or pylons.

Comment: Yes that may be the reason behind this but are there any other possibilities?

Comment: Yes. They could be alien spaceships. Or ball lightning. Or Chinese lanterns. ... What do you think the lights in the foreground are? They look similar.

Comment: Have you read about the Marfa Lights?  If you G the term, you get images somewhat like yours and also the Wikipedia article, (which some say was written by aliens to convince us they are just  car headlights). You could do a G image search for similar images and try SkepticsSE

Comment: -1 This is not a physiscs question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteorites would not suddenly appear at ground level, would not hover, and would not move sideways.  Meteorites generally appear as fast-moving pinpoints of white light descending downward from the upper sky, and disappear before they reach ground.

These could be [ball lightning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_lightning), which is known to move up and down, to hover, and to be repelled by buildings and landscape.  Ball lightning lasts longer than other types of lightning.  Here's a video of ball lightning: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4vV3KxQ16c.  You get views of various kinds later in the video.

Or these might be the notorious [Min Min lights](http://www.news.com.au/technology/environment/natural-wonders/the-mystery-of-queenslands-eerie-min-min-lights/news-story/b63356761813663c76c5810485415f6d), if these pictures were taken in Australia.